# Narrowband Gaussian Noise

Tags: noise, gaussian

Could anyone lead me on the right path on where I could get more information in regards to a narrowband Gaussian signal can be modeled as:

$$
X(t)\cos(2\pi f t)+Y(t)\sin(2\pi f t)
$$

where $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ are the in phase and quadrature phase noise amplitudes.

Comment: Your question body doesn't match the title.  The title is about bandwidth, the body is about representing an analytic signal.  Could you _edit your question_ to harmonize these two, and preferably to the subject you actually want to know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some information at least in Section 1-4, "Narrowband Noise and Envelope Detection", in the book: M. Schwartz, W. R. Bennett, and S. Stein, "Communication Systems and Techniques".

This old book, published 1966, [can be accessed online if one signs in to IEEEXplore.org using their own personal account.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5271291) [Full book here.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/book/5271273) Otherwise one could maybe find a physical copy at some technical university library. I'm afraid I don't know any good public online sources.

Comment: Thanks! Added the direct link into your answer. Much better than vague references to it.

Comment: You are welcome! I agree, the direct link is much better. Thanks for the link update!

Comment: Thank you very much!